# Understanding TypeScript Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am studying TypeScript for Bacend development and I came along this [backend git project repo](https://github.com/martin-nderitu/inventory-manager-backend) that uses Sequelize library. I have researched about this topic but there are varying examples with different code format. I am particularly confused with this code snippets

```
export class Sale extends Model<SaleAttributes, SaleCreationAttributes>
    implements SaleAttributes {
    .
    . *removed other codes*
    .
    // possible inclusions
    declare readonly products?: Product[];

    // associations
    declare static associations: {
        products:  Association<Sale, Product>;
    }

    static associate (models: Models) {
        this.belongsTo(models.Product, {
            as: "product",
            foreignKey: {
                name: "productId",
                allowNull: false
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[Complete File Link](https://github.com/martin-nderitu/inventory-manager-backend/blob/master/src/models/sale.ts)

What is the use of the `declare static associations` and `static associate` in this context? Also, if I have OneToMany relationship, should I change `Associate<Sale,Product>` to `HasMany<Sale,Product>` or changing `this.belongsTo` to `this.hasMany` will suffice?